# Comparing word to targeted words in dictionary

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, spell-checking

I'm trying to write a program in JAVA that stores a dictionary in a hashmap (each word under a different key) and compares a given word to the words in the dictionary and comes up with a spelling suggestion if it is not found in the dictionary -- basically a spell check program.

I already came up with the comparison algorithm (i.e. Needleman-Wunsch then Levenshtein distance), etc., but got stuck when it came figuring out what words in the dictionary-hashmap to compare the word to i.e. "hellooo".

I cannot compare "ohelloo" [should be corrected to "hello" to each word in the dictionary b/c that would take too long and I cannot compare it to all words int the dictionary starting with 'o' b/c it's supposed to be "hello".

Any ideas?

Comment: You   can compare all shifts of the given word and choose the best fit. For example: 'ohelloo', 'hellooo', 'elloooh', ...

Comment: okay, but then how would I select a subset of words in the dictionary to compare the word to?

Comment: I don't think a hashmap is a good data structure for solving this problem. Using a trie / suffix tree you would be able to quickly find all words with the given prefix.

Comment: but what if the spelling error is in the prefix?

Answer (score 0):

The most common spelling mistakes are

- Delete a letter (smaller word OR word split)
- Swap adjacent letters
- Alter letter (QWERTY adjacent letters)
- Insert letter

Some reports say that 70-90% of mistakes fall in the above categories (edit distance 1)

Take a look on the url below that provides a solution for single or double mistakes (edit distance 1 or 2). Almost everything you'll need is there!

[How to write a spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

FYI: You can find implementation in various programming languages in the bottom of the aforementioned article. I've used it in some of my projects, practical accuracy is really good, sometimes more than 95+% as claimed by the author.

--Based on OP's comment--
If you don't want to pre-compute every possible alteration and then search on the map, I suggest that you use a patricia trie ([radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)) instead of a HashMap. Unfortunately, you will again need to handle the "first-letter mistake" (eg remove first letter or swap first with the second, or just replace it with a Qwerty adjacent) and you can limit your search with high probability.

You can even combine it with an extra Index Map or Trie with "reversed" words or an extra index that omits first N characters (eg first 2), so you can catch errors occurred on prefix only.

Comment: Thanks; I already came up with the scoring/comparison algorithm of a word with a given dictionary word. My question was about which words in the dictionary to compare a word to i.e. how to select similar words in the dictionary